# Laravel query builder: DB::raw with IF statement gives wrong results

Tags: mysql, laravel, if-statement

I have a query which works in mysql, but when doing it in laravel I get wrong results.
**update**: The Laravel version is 4.2.

The query retrieves all books, but if a book has "visibility_school" (boolean), then the current user's school must match the book writer's school - so I used an IF statement for that.

This **mysql** query works: (see the `WHERE IF` line, where I hard coded a value 2 (`schools.id = 2`) to compare to for testing, normally it is dynamic)

```
SELECT book.*, user.name AS name, user.school_class AS schoolClass, schools.name as 
       schoolName, count(DISTINCT book.id) AS overallCount, 
       AVG(book_rating.mark) AS rating 
FROM book
LEFT JOIN user ON book.user_id = user.id
LEFT JOIN book_tag ON book.id = book_tag.book_id
LEFT JOIN book_rating ON book.id = book_rating.book_id
LEFT JOIN schools ON schools.id = user.school_id
WHERE IF(book.visibility_school = 1, IF(schools.id = 2, 1, 0), 1) = 1       
AND book.published = 1                      
AND book.deleted = 0                 
GROUP BY book.id
```

When doing this in **Laravel query builder**, my code looks like:

```
$books = DB::table('book')
   ->select(DB::raw("book.*, user.name AS name, user.school_class AS schoolClass, 
               schools.name as schoolName,count(DISTINCT book.id) AS overallCount, 
               AVG(book_rating.mark) AS rating"))
->leftJoin('user', 'book.user_id', '=', 'user.id') 
->leftJoin('book_tag', 'book.id', '=', 'book_tag.book_id')    
->leftJoin('book_rating', 'book.id', '=', 'book_rating.book_id')    
->leftJoin('schools', 'schools.id', '=', 'user.school_id')  
->where(DB::raw("IF(book.visibility_school = 1, IF(schools.id = '?', 1, 0), 1) = 1"),$currentUserSchoolId)
->where('book.published',Book::STATUS_PUBLISHED)
->where('book.deleted',0) 
->groupBy('book.id');
```

The mysql query correctly returns 5 published books, and if I set `schools.id = 3` an extra book only visible to members of a certain school id is included.

The laravel code however returns no books, with two exceptions:

1. If I set `schools.id = 0`, I get 1 result, the one book only visible to members of a certain school (which should be id 3).
2. If I set `schools.id = 1` - I get the 5 published books. If I set any other id's I get no results.

There is no difference if I put `$currentUserSchoolId` inside an array `[$currentUserSchoolId]`. 
Also the `Book::STATUS_PUBLISHED` property equals 1, so there's no difference to the mysql code version there.

So laravel seems to evaluate the "`where if`" line to **false** even if `visibility_school` is not 1.

**--------- Update ---------**

After a suggestion , I changed the `where if` line (and also added to that: `AND schools.id <> 0`):

```
->where(DB::raw("book.visibility_school <> 1 OR schools.id = '?' AND schools.id <> 0"), 
      $currentUserSchoolId)
```

Now I get the published books always, so that's good, but I still don't get the book visible to a matching school id. If I set `schools.id = 3` I should get it, and it still works in mysql. But if I set it to 0 (and remove AND schools.id <> 0) I get that book too - so laravel thinks that the school id is 0 for some reason. So that's my current problem.

Comment: I think your condition is really `WHERE (book.visibility_school != 1 OR schools.id = 2) AND ..`.

Comment: I guess that's a better way to write it, but I think the logic is the same. When I added this to laravel: DB::raw("book.visibility_school <> 1 OR schools.id = '?' AND schools.id <> 0" - the published books show up as they should, so maybe laravel didn't like the syntax I used. But I don't get the "visibility_school" book when I put the matching school id 3. Laravel seems to think that that book has school id 0 (because it matches when I put school.id = 0 (and remove the extra clause I added "AND schools.id <> 0"). In mysql the query works though.

Answer (score 1):

When using parameters binding you don't need to pass the quotations around the question mark, so `?` and not `'?'`.

```
DB::raw("IF(book.visibility_school = 1, IF(schools.id = ?, 1, 0), 1) = 1"),$currentUserSchoolId)
```

However as others suggested your checks can be simplified using normal and/or operations

Comment: If I remove the quotation around ? , I get "SQLSTATE[HY093]: Invalid parameter number " . I use laravel 4.2, maybe that version requires quotation(?)

Answer (score -1):

Is there any reason you are not taking advantage from [the ORM provided by Laravel](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/eloquent)?

With all the [relationships](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/eloquent-relationships) well set in your [models](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/eloquent#defining-models), you should get a more or less similar result with the following code:

**MyController.php**

```
$currentUserId = Auth::id();
$books = Book::with(['tag', 'rating', 'user', 'user.school' => function ($query) {
        $query->selectRaw('name as schoolName')->addSelect('id');
    }])
    ->whereHas('user', function ($query) use ($currentUserId) {
        $query->where('id', $currentUserId);
    })
    ->where('published', Book::STATUS_PUBLISHED)
    ->where('visibility_school', true)
    ->where('deleted', false)
    ->get();
}
```

Comment: I don't want to use it too much for complex queries because it's slower. The query should also return all results were book.visibility_school = 0, but if it's 1 the book writer's school  should match current user's school.